# porting over database changes to SQL Server Reporting Services to avoid breaking reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, refactoring-databases

When database changes are made (tables and column names renamed or eliminated), my shop struggles with broke reports which we react to after deployment. There is no established practice to fix the reports to reflect the changes before going live with the database changes.

I have the databases set up as SQL Server database projects in VS and have them committed to GIT. The reporting services files (`.rdl` files) are in GIT as well. Googled everywhere to see if a database project can be connected to no avail.

Whenever a database object is changed (renamed a column for example) in a database project, I am looking for an efficient way to fix the references to the renamed column in the SQL Server Reporting Services project.

Comment: That has nothing to do with sql reporting services.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the best practice is using stored procedures as data source instead of writing sql query in the report. that way you can simply edit the query inside report stored procedure whenever necessary.

If not you have to open the report and then edit the query and redeploy the report.

Tip: whenever you come across a SQL query as dataset source in SSRS, change it to stored 
     procedure ASAP. it's easy, because you already have the query.

Comment: It's too late now.  Reports have been written by report writers, and there are hundreds of them.